# scalar object '***' requires one element in initializer

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm trying to initialize an SDL_Color structure in c++:

```
SDL_Color* RED = {255, 255, 255, 255};     // r, g, b, a
```

It compiled fine in C, but in c++ i keep getting this error.

**error: scalar object 'RED' requires one element in initializer
 SDL_Color* RED = {255, 255, 255, 255};**

Comment: `SDL_Color RED = {255, 255, 255, 255};`

Comment: Turn on warnings. `warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Comment: my warnings are on, i didn't get one, i'm not using an IDE

Comment: @theCodeGuy Neither am I? But it's an error to assign an array to a pointer (or at least doesn't do what you expect).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set your object with an initializer list

```
SDL_Color RED = {255, 255, 255, 255};
```

But you have a `SDL_Color` pointer!

```
SDL_Color* RED = new SDL_Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
```

Comment: Thanks, i totally forgot about the pointer. It shouldn't be a pointer.